# CURL to check if REST API is responding

Tags: c#, rest, curl, jenkins

I want to use CURL to check if the server the REST API is hosted is UP or responding

I have a c#.NET REST API `http://localhost:55223/api/Demo/PostData`?

I want to check if the server that hosted REST api is reponding before i make a call to my REST service

I am using following way to check i wanted to know if it is the right way

[image: Code]

Comment: Why do you want to check that first? The fact that you get some response by calling the root URL of your server does not mean your service call will return successfully. I would suggest you hit your service straight and skip the check. You will need some error handling around the call anyway.

Comment: That is like calling your mom on the phone and hang on if she answers, just to call her again, because now you know she will answer the call.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-returns.html

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue with the url design here. Since, post data is always sent in the body and as a post request, whereas the URL and the request in the above example depicts a totally different scenario.

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d 'Add body here or remove this text and -d flag' 'http://localhost:55223/api/Demo/Post'
```

This would totally suffice a correct request though you need to edit the **-d** flag within the command for your request.

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
CURL='/usr/bin/curl'
if CURL -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d 'Add body here or remove this text and -d flag' 'http://localhost:55223/api/Demo/PostData'
else
 echo "Not Found"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a QA and I just raised a bug related to this. I configured the client app to reach an invalid API host and hoped that the client app would fail but I discovered that even when the client app has not received a response, it keeps retrying for half an hour instead of just telling the customer right away that the api is not available at the moment.

I say, checking the host availbility before sending requests (or uploading files in my case) will not hurt and will give a faster feedback to the user if there is a technical issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to hit the API to test it, go through Postman to send out those requests.

Comment: This isn't an answer, it is a comment

Comment: @maccettura, of course it's not an answer. There was no question asked in the op.. ;)